# The fundamental group of the quotient groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a simply-connected and connected topological group  and let $\Lambda$ be a closed discrete subgroup of $G$. Now, $\pi:G\to G/\Lambda $ is a covering map. What is $\pi_1(G/\Lambda)$? I know it has the same cardinality as $\Lambda$, but is it isomorphic (as groups) to $\Lambda$?

Comment: It is isomorphic to $\Lambda$ : prove that the group of deck transformations of a normal covering $p_* :E\to E/G$ (for nice hypotheses on the $G$-action of course, and on $E$, but they are satisfied here, assuming $G$ is locally path-connected) is isomorphic to $\pi_1(E/G)/p_*(\pi_1(E))$; and show that this group of deck transformations is also $G$